# Wordpress nav bar renders incorrectly IE7

Tags: html, css, wordpress, navigation

I am having some problems getting this Wordpress nav bar to render correctly in IE7.  Im not sure if my CSS is missing something I should be including or what.  If anyone has any ideas I am all open to suggestions. blog.coolbakers.com

I was also contemplating switching the nav over to a css/html only rollover nav bar, but I have a feeling that I am simply missing something simple and really would prefer to not go through all of that if it an easy fix, as I have not worked in a Wordpress environment much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using an IE7/IE6 only CSS stylesheet if you don't want to waste your time finding a solution just for one old browser, do this by adding the below in your header.php file

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" src="yourfolder/ie7.css"/>
<![endif]-->
```

And add this style to the new file to fix your problem:

```
#header .widget-area-menu { margin-top: 26px }
```